# Extract associative array from string php using regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am working on a laravel project and I need to extend the functionality of the translations:find artisan command that is forked from barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager method findTranslations. The default regex looks like this:

```
$pattern = "[^\w|>]".           // Must not have an alphanum or _ or > before real method
"(".implode('|', $functions) .")".   // Must start with one of the functions
"\(".                            // Match opening parenthesis
"[\'\"]".                        // Match " or '
"(".                             // Start a new group to match:
"[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+".                // Must start with group
"([.|\/][^\1)]+)+".              // Be followed by one or more items/keys
")".                             // Close group
"[\'\"]".                        // Closing quote
"[\),]";                         // Close parentheses or new parameter
```

The default functionality loads a file as a string such as this:

`<?php\n
\n
echo trans('testing.here-should-be-some-argument', ['some_argument' => '1']);`

and finds the "testing.here-should-be-some-argument" part to store it it later.

My goal is the adjust the functionality to work as follows:

1. First select the entire `testing.here-should-be-some-argument', ['some_argument' => '1']` part of string.
2. Extract `['some_argument' => '1']` from the string
3. Get the `some_argument` from that string.

I currently at step 1 trying to figure it out how to account for both single and double quotes in the string.

My end-game is that I could try and match the argument names (e.g. "some_argument")against the key of the translation "here-should-be-some-argument" and if found replace the argument in the string like this "here-should-be-:some_argument" so that the person who translates the given text, would know that it must use it as an argument.

Comment: There's no `translations:find` command. Are you referring to a specific package?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it has been forked from laravel-translations-manager package. I have edited the question too.